# Duplicate sheet without coping codes attached to that sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question regarding the code you suggest for the deletion of codes. I would like to erase all the codes activated on the Excel Object in the duplicated sheet "Overview 10 years (2)" so that I can continue without that it runs and interferes with other codes. Is there missing something in my way of doing it?

```
Sheets(Array("Overview 10 years", "Overview monthly")).Select
Sheets("Overview 10 years").Activate
Sheets(Array("Overview 10 years", "Overview monthly")).Copy Before:=Sheets(1 _
    )
Sheets("Overview 10 years (2)").Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

' Get the code/object name of the new sheet...
Dim StrObjectName As String
StrObjectName = Sheets("Overview 10 years (2)").CodeName

' Remove all lines from its code module...
With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(StrObjectName).CodeModule
.DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
End With
```

I would need to erase lines 1-15, so that it does no longer interfere with other codes.

Comment: just create new, empty sheet and copy your content there (you do it anyway) insetad of copying entire sheet

Comment: The problem is that on that sheet there are like 7 graphs that have to be duplicated and made dependent on the new sheets data. Because of that, I guess that I can't just copy the original sheets to a new sheet. 
But when duplicating I would like to erase all the codes on the new sheet that were copied from the original sheet